# C string definition of unknown length

Tags: c, string, casting

I need to store data (Of previously unknown format/size) inside a string for processing later (To be stored in an XML file)

How do I do this?

As you can see, the code below will generate a segfault.

```
char * type;
char * output;

for (i=0; i< 10; i++){ 

if(strcmp(GTK_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i])), "GtkAdjustment") == 0){
    type = "spin";
    sprintf(output, "%f", gtk_adjustment_get_value(GTK_ADJUSTMENT(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i]))));

}else if(strcmp(GTK_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i])), "GtkCheckButton") == 0){
    type = "check";
    sprintf(output, "%d", gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i]))));

}else if(strcmp(GTK_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i])), "GSList") == 0){
    type = "radio"; // Loop through grouped buttons and find active one
    sprintf(output, "%d", g_slist_position(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i]),
                g_slist_find_custom(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i]),
                    NULL, (GCompareFunc) searchRadio)));

}else if(strcmp(GTK_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i])), "GtkComboBox") == 0){
    type = "combo";
    sprintf(output, "%d", gtk_combo_box_get_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i]))));

}else if(strcmp(GTK_OBJECT_TYPE_NAME(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i])), "GtkEntry") == 0){
    type = "entry";
    output = (char *) gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,allocate[i])));

}
[...]
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. Have you tried simplyfing the snippet? It would help to understand the problem more easily.

Comment: A great advert for not using underscores in names. and see snprintf at http://libslack.org/manpages/snprintf.3.html, if your system has it.

Comment: The underscores are part of GTK which is the second largest (IIRC) UI library in the world :) Sorry about the snippet size, it was just there for the curious (The text above it has the whole question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your platform has snprintf or similar (most do), then you want something like this:

```
int n = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%s is %d", somestring, someinteger );
char * p = malloc( n + 1 );
sprintf( p, "%s is %d", somestring, someinteger );
```

The first call to `snprintf` returns how many chars would be needed to store the formatted output, but doesn't actually do any formatting. Then you allocate the space needed and do the real formatting.

Comment: Great! Why n+1 though? Wouldn't the terminator be included?

Comment: No, it returns the number of formatted characters, not including the null terminator.

Comment: Ok, thanks! By the way, wouldn't `char * p` be freed when the function ends or do you *really* need to use `free()`?

Comment: You really need to use free(). In C, nothing is ever done for you. If you want to simplify memory management, use C++.

Answer (score 4):

In general, to "store data of an unknown size" in a C string, you have two choices:

1. Allocate a buffer large enough to hold any expected size (which means you would truncate the data if it exceeds that size), or
2. Dynamically allocate a buffer (using `malloc()`) that is large enough to hold the data. Don't forget to `free()` it, too.

Your code is using an uninitialised pointer `output` and that is why it is segfaulting. You will need to do one of the above.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I would prefer to use `mallo()` the "Robust" way, but I don't know how to get the length of a decimal/float converted to a string before the actual conversion.

Comment: For a decimal or float, it would be much simpler to use a fixed size buffer. You *know* that the result of converting a value to a string won't exceed a certain size, so you can declare a small buffer on the stack with enough space to hold any value.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allocating `output` and that is precisely why you are getting segmentation faults. As it is in the code provided, `output` has not been initialized. Your compiler should warn you of this.

If you know a safe maximum size, you can simply allocate it on the stack:

```
char output[512];
```

...if the maximum size was 512 bytes. Otherwise, you can look at `malloc` to allocate memory off the heap.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to pre-allocate a big enough buffer or to truncate the output to size:

1. Pre-process the generation (no writes, just count the lengthes) and allocate a suitable buffer for the second (really write) pass
2. Write to 'unlimited' storage: a file